# Is a $(1, 1)$ tensor a vector-valued one-form?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, differential-forms

$(1, 1)$ tensor can eat a vector and spits out a vector. Hence it looks like it can be seen as a vector-valued one-form?

Comment: Yes it is. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks! Any cautions/pitfalls?

Comment: Some care must be taken when you construct derivatives of p-forms not being scalars. For instance the covariant exterior derivative will have extra terms.